# How do I solve this derivative given limited information?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Given $y=\cos^{-1}(t^{-1})-\sec^{-1}(t)$, I am to find $y'$.

I am also given the following definitions:

$\frac{d}{dx}\cos^{-1}(x)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$\frac{d}{dx}\sec^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

I know that the final answer is 0. However, I have no idea how I would show that working off the definitions I've been given here.

When I ask Wolfram Alpha what the derivative of $\sec^{-1}(x)$ is, it is using an entirely different definition (without the absolute value in there):

$\frac{d}{dx}\sec^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^{-2}}}$

Using that definition, I'm able to solve the derivative, but I'm not sure how I would have known to do that. How do I find the derivative using only the first two definitions provided? Or is there some way to show that the two derivatives of $\sec^{-1}(x)$ are identical?

Comment: this is a trick question. remember that $\sec x = \frac1{\cos x}$

Comment: Do $\cos^{-1}$ and $\sec^{-1}$ have the same relationship?

Comment: $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: $\cos^{-1}(\frac1{\sec x})= x$

Comment: It is easy. Use the fact that $\frac{d}{dt}\cos^{-1} u = \frac{-u^{\prime}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$.

Comment: Regarding David Holden's hint, note that putting $u = {\cos}^{-1}\frac{1}{t}$ we get (take cosine of both sides) $\cos u = \frac{1}{t},$ and hence (take the reciprocal of both sides) $\sec u = t,$ which gives $u = {\sec}^{-1}t.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sec(x) = \frac1{\cos(x)} \newcommand\arcsec{\mathop{\rm arcsec}}$ so 
$$\mathop{\rm arcsec}(\frac1t) \stackrel{t=\cos x}= \mathop{\rm arcsec}(\sec(x)) = x = \arccos(t)$$
So in total
$$y(t) = \arccos(\frac1t) - \arcsec(t) = \arcsec(t) - \arcsec(t) = 0$$
Thus $y'(t) = 0$ trivially.

Alternatively if you want to show that
$$\frac1{x^2 \sqrt{1-x^{-2}}} = \frac1{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
Remember that $x^2 = |x|^2$ and $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, so
$$x^2 \sqrt{1-x^{-2}} = |x||x|\sqrt{1-x^{-2}} =  |x|\sqrt{x^2(1-x^{-2})} = |x|\sqrt{x^2-1}$$
And by taking reciprocals, the claim follows.